# Graphical form for sudo configured as other user than current user

Tags: 18.04, sudo

I've installed my computer (Ubuntu 18.04) with an user called 'localadmin'.

Then I've created another user "thomas", which is in group sudo.

If I'am logged in as 'thomas' and a graphical program ask for sudo authentication (e.g. gedit admin:///etc/fstab),I have to enter the password for the user 'localadmin'.

In the terminal, e.g. `sudo vi /etc/fstab`, the user 'thomas' will be elevated, as expected.

How can I change the graphical ui to ask for the right user for elevating?

Thomas

Comment: Good question - I don't think the [gvfs admin backend](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/gvfs/backends) is well documented - it seems to use `libpolkit` under the hood, so presumably there is some kind of policykit schema that controls this

Comment: ... in fact, I suspect that's the intent of  `subject.local && subject.active && subject.isInGroup ("sudo"))` in the `/usr/share/polkit-1/rules.d/org.gtk.vfs.file-operations.rules` file. Just to clarify, did you log out and back in after adding `thomas` to group `sudo`?

Comment: @steeldriver: Just to clarify, did you log out and back in after adding thomas to group sudo?  - Yes i did.

Comment: I've backed up the entire userhome before installing ubuntu (from scratch), after the install was completed, i've restored the whole userhome.

Because i've created the user 'localadmin' before 'thomas' my user id is now 1001 instead of 1000 before the install - is the userid for sudoing in Gui maybe cached somewhere?

Thomas

Comment: Not so far as I know - you did add `thomas` to the `sudo` *group*, right - not as an individual user entry in /etc/sudoers?

Comment: ``groups thomas``
thomas : sudo

Comment: Hmm... in that case I'm out of ideas - sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `groups` command showed that the user 'thomas' was in sudo group, the graphical tool 'users and groups' showed no membership.

Adding the user in the 'users and groups' tool solved the issue.

The question why the command line and the gui showed differences is still unanswered.

Thomas